# How to handle installed plugins via `composer.json` during update?

Tags: composer-php, shopware6

I have the problem that during a Shopware 6 update (e.g. 6.4.18.0 -> 6.4.19.0) the root `composer.json` changes.

Since it is possible to install plugins via `composer require` all the required plugins and installed plugins are missing after the update.

How do i handle that? What is the best-practice for this case?

Comment: Did you replace the composer.json with the one from Shopware 6? What we do is, we merge both versions. The upstream changes with our changes. We use a git merge in the production template. Can you describe your current upgrade process more?

Comment: I am updating the "normal update way" by downloading the update-package and then overwriting existing files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you install shopware in the first place? When you install shopware over the webinstaller, then you should update over that way as well and changes in the `composer.json` will be overwritten by an update so you have to add those changes manually again.

If you set up your project using composer you should update by pulling the latest changes and if you have manual changes in the `composer.json`, those changes will be merged via git.

With the new [symfony flex setup](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/installation/flex) all of this should not be necessary anymore and your root `composer.json` should not be touched anymore during updates. The flex setup will be the default setup starting with 6.5 and also the webupdater will switch the existing installations to this setup.

You can follow [this guide](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/installation/flex#how-do-i-migrate-from-production-template-to-symfony-flex) on how to switch to the new setup.